# Swift value of Double.infinity

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I use a property IBInspectable property and I would like to use a value of kind `Double.infinity`

It looks like this:

```
@IBInspectable public var value: Double = Double.infinity
```

My issues are:

1) In the interface builder we cannot define text for Double like `inf`, how can I determine a Double.infinity?

2) Is it normal that even if the property has a default value, the interface builder only show `--`?

Comment: `--` means default value.

Comment: Ok so `--` means `Double.Infinity`. Too bad IB isn't more explicit for the user and we cannot customise this placeholder text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Sweeper I found a solution.
`@IBInspectable public var value: Double = Double.infinity` means the default value will be `Double.infinity` so to set the property to this value, we just nee to let the IB field empty with `--`.